# passing an element id to a function called inside a onclick on javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a created `<li>` which I have added an `onclick` function to it. The problem is that I call a function inside `<th>` `onclick` function and I'm trying to pass the `<li>` `id` to it.

The `checkboxHours` function doesn't seem to get the `id` tho.

```js
function changeHours() {
  document.getElementById("courtTimes").replaceChildren();

  //Change hours
  var sports = $('input[name="sports"]:checked').val()
  courtChecked = $('input[name="sportCourts"]:checked').val()
  dayChecked = $('input[name="daysRowItem"]:checked').val()

  var listID = "";
  for (const i in courtTimes[sports][courtChecked][dayChecked]) {
    var hour = courtTimes[sports][courtChecked][dayChecked][i]
    var listItem = document.createElement("li");
    listID = "courtTimesItem" + i;
    listItem.setAttribute = ("id", listID);
    listItem.className = "courtTimesItem"
    listItem.onclick = function() {
      checkBoxHours(this.id)
    };
    listItem.innerHTML = '<label><input type="checkbox" class="hoursCheckbox" name="courtTimesItem"><div style="margin-top: 0.75vh">' + hour + ':00</div></label>';
    document.getElementById("courtTimes").appendChild(listItem);
  }
}

function checkBoxHours(ab) {
  document.getElementById("monthTxt").innerHTML += ab; //check if works
}
```

```css
#courtTimes {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: 25vh;
  height: 47vh;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  float: top;
}

.courtTimesItem {
  margin-top: 8vw;
  width: 50vw;
  height: 5vh;
  margin-left: 17vw;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgb(112, 112, 112);
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Heebo-Regular';
  padding-bottom: 1vh;
  border-radius: 1.5vw;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="courtTimes"></ul>
```

Comment: Have you created the variable 'listID' before, in your code somewhere? You are not creating it with var, like the listItem, which you should be doing.

Comment: yes i have created it beforehand

Comment: Did you add the list item to the DOM? Can you edit your question and make a snippet (using toolbar) so we can actually run & reproduce?

Comment: I haven't created a function like that before. Maybe someone knows if it's possible. It seems a bit odd to me.

Comment: `listItem.addEventListener("click", function () {checkBoxHours(this.id)});` is recommended

Comment: Please update the code to be a [mcve] - we are missing fields and courtTimes object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
var listItem = document.createElement("li");
listID = "courtTimesItem" + i;
listItem.setAttribute("id", listID);
listItem.onclick = function () {checkBoxHours(this.id)};
```

I assume you used setAttribute as string variable, not as function.